# ApplicationCommands.Open event handler binding

Tags: .net, wpf

I try to add open command logic to RibbonButton in WPF application. In XAML was setted RibbonButton Command attribute.
Binding was added to saving command. After application start error occurs "Invalid typecast System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo to System.Reflection.MethodInfo". The XAML and the code are shown below. Please help with the solution of this problem.

```html
<ribbon:RibbonWindow.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding  Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Executed="{Binding Execute}" CanExecute="{Binding CanExecute}">

        </CommandBinding>
    </ribbon:RibbonWindow.CommandBindings>

<ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="OpenButton"
                                         LargeImageSource="Images/Open_16x16.png"
                                         Label="Open" Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"/>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow, ICommand
    {
       ...
       public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
          {
              return (true);
          }
       public void Execute(object parameter)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Executed");
          }
       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove Binding. Refer the code here.. Executed="Execute" CanExecute="CanExecute"

Comment: Agree with @AyyappanSubramanian, remove the Binding, and leave only the name of the method : http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/

Comment: "Execute="Execute" CanExecute="CanExecute"" throws error is like a "Can't find method in MainWindow ... that accept MainWindow in first parameter" for both methods.